# Rails 3: Dependent => :deny or similar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, dependencies, activemodel

I have a model "location", which has many "courses"

If I destroy a location, I'd like the destroy request to be rejected unless there are no relationships between the location and any courses. I assume there's some pretty concise way of doing this, but I can't find anything.

Soo...what's the most elegant/simple/concise way of enabling this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Location...

```
before_destroy do |l|
  return false unless l.courses.nil?
end
```

Comment: Pretty simple, kinda seems like a hack, but this should work perfectly. Just be sure you only call "destroy" on your locations, not delete (which skips callbacks).

Comment: I think courses will be an empty array not nil. `l.courses.empty?` would be better.